# What's the most idiomatic way to create directories recursivelly in Go?

Tags: go

I need to create a given nested directory structure using Go, but I couldn't figure out the most practical and idiomatic way to do that. Some inspiration:

Bash: `mkdir -p some/deep/path`

C#  : `IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"some/deep/path")`

PHP : `mkdir("some/deep/path", 0777, true)`

Java: `new File("some/deep/path").mkdirs()`

Go  : ?

Requirement is that operation should be silent if path is already in place (just like in the other language examples).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would be `new File("some/deep/path").mkdirs()` in java. Your java Directory thing doesn't follow java naming conventions and certainly doesn't exist in the standard library. (or `Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("some/deep/path"))` as per [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html#create);

Comment: updated Java example, old one was tested using brain runtime so big chance of erros ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and see if [`os.MkdirAll`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#MkdirAll) does create all the folder that you need.

> `MkdirAll` creates a directory named path, **along with any necessary parents**, and returns `nil`, or else returns an error.
>   The permission bits perm are used for all directories that `MkdirAll` creates.
>   If path is already a directory, `MkdirAll` does nothing and returns `nil`.

See its [test class](https://golang.org/src/pkg/os/path_test.go).

Note that, when you look [at its implementation](http://golang.org/src/pkg/os/path.go?s=488:535#L9), `MkdirAll` isn't exactly "atomic".

Comment: `mkdir -p` doesn't seem to be either, judging from [this](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-202.2/mkdir/mkdir.c)

Comment: @Cubic I agree. The "atomic" requirement isn't easy to meet with that kind of os operation.

Comment: I'll remove the atomic requirement. It's quite utopic to have it by default, but easy to implement if needed.